# Create logical OR (||) operator dynamically from objects in an array

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

I am looking for a solution in JavaScript to turn an `Array` of `objects` into a logical OR (||) operator.

An example of what I would like to achieve is

```
const logic =
  (scrollPosition > 0 - 61 && scrollPosition < 1511 - 61) ||
  (scrollPosition > 3021 - 61 && scrollPosition < 4532 - 61) ||
  (scrollPosition > 4531.5 - 61 && scrollPosition < 6041.5 - 61) ||
  (scrollPosition > 9063 - 61 && scrollPosition < 10574 - 61) ||
  (scrollPosition > 10573.5 - 61 && scrollPosition < 12083.5 - 61) ||
  (scrollPosition > 12084 - 61 && scrollPosition < 13091 - 61);
```

How do I get this outcome from

```
const data = [
  { start: 0, finish: 1511 },
  { start: 3021, finish: 4532 },
  { start: 4531.5, finish: 6041.5 },
  { start: 9063, finish: 10574 },
  { start: 10573.5, finish: 12083.5 },
  { start: 12084, finish: 13091 },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.some` checks if at least one element matches the condition, making it equivalent to chained ORs.

```
data.some(x => scrollPosition > x.start - 61 && scrollPosition < x.finish - 61)
```